# xcode 4.? + ios 6 works at lion 10.7.2?

Tags: iphone, xcode, osx-lion, ios6

I got a working mac os lion 10.7.2 system, and I don't want to upgrade to mountain lion so I can begin ios 6 development. Which Xcode version should I install so I can get ios 6 set up to work? My current Xcode is 4.2, how to install ios 6 sdk and simulator in it?

Comment: Have you tried installing the latest?

Comment: @yong ho: did you get this fixed?

Answer (score 0):

To do iOS 6 development you need Xcode 4.5. It should still work on Lion and can be installed through the Mac App Store. The iOS 6 SDK and Simulator will be automatically installed with it.

See also: http://www.iclarified.com/24572/apple-releases-xcode-45-featuring-sdks-for-ios-6-mountain-lion-108

Comment: Xcode 4.5 will work with lion 10.7.4 or later, but I got lion 10.7.2.

Comment: I understood you didn't want to upgrade to Mountain Lion, but why not install the patches through Software Update that will bring you to 10.7.4? Most likely you're missing out on security fixes right now as well...

Comment: Because I am running a hackintosh system, and I don't want to spend more time to make the lion perfect again. I guess I have to install mountain lion and install kexts one more time.

Answer (score 0):

If You have the developer account then download the latest version of xcode with it's .dmg file and also you find the older version of the xcode i would prefer to instal new version of the xcode 4.5 to building the IOS 6 Application.

```
https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode
```

Here to download the versions of the xcode

Comment: But the xcode 4.5 won't work with lion 10.7.2, and I don't want to update mac os.